# SQL how to union selections and exclude one?

Tags: mysql, sql, select, union

At first I want to select first 5 rows with highest raiting.

```
SELECT
        e.id embed_id,
    e.type embed_type,
    e.embed,
    IF(ul.embed_id IS NULL,0,1) liked,
    (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM user_likes ula WHERE ula.embed_id = e.id) u_likes
FROM `embeds` e
LEFT JOIN user_likes ul ON ul.embed_id = e.id AND ul.user_id = 1
ORDER BY u_likes DESC
LIMIT 5
```

Then I want to select other rows ordering just by id, excluding first 5 rows selected before.

```
SELECT
    e.id embed_id,
    e.type embed_type,
    e.embed,
    IF(ul.embed_id IS NULL,0,1) liked,
    (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM user_likes ula WHERE ula.embed_id = e.id) u_likes
FROM `embeds` e
LEFT JOIN user_likes ul ON ul.embed_id = e.id AND ul.user_id = 1
ORDER BY embed_id
/* HOW TO EXCLUDE FIRTS SELECTION ? */
```

And then I want to union these two selections.

How to exclude first one from another and then union alltogether? Is it possible to use temporary table?

Also I've tried `WHERE NOT EXISTS` but it doesn't work:

```
SELECT
    e.id embed_id,
    e.type embed_type,
    e.embed,
    IF(ul.embed_id IS NULL,0,1) liked,
    (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM user_likes ula WHERE ula.embed_id = e.id) u_likes
FROM `embeds` e
LEFT JOIN user_likes ul ON ul.embed_id = e.id AND ul.user_id = 1
WHERE NOT EXISTS (
    SELECT
        e.id embed_id,
        (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM user_likes ula WHERE ula.embed_id = e.id) u_likes
    FROM `embeds` e
    LEFT JOIN user_likes ul ON ul.embed_id = e.id AND ul.user_id = 1
    ORDER BY u_likes DESC
    LIMIT 5
)
```

No rows for such query as result.

Any advice will be appreciated, thanks!

Comment: Sample data and desired results would help.  I don't understand why you are joining to `user_likes` *and* using a subquery to count them.

Comment: Because it is pivot table containing user ids and embed ids. Thanks for great advice!

Comment: See [Why should I provide a Minimal Reproducible Example for a very simple SQL query?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-a-minimal-reproducible-example-for-a-very-simple-sql-query)  ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you please check this below query solve your purpose or not-

```
SELECT *,CASE WHEN (@rownum := @rownum + 1) < 6 THEN @rownum ELSE 6 END 
FROM
(
    SELECT
        e.id embed_id,
        e.type embed_type,
        e.embed,
        IF(ul.embed_id IS NULL,0,1) liked,
        (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM user_likes ula WHERE ula.embed_id = e.id) u_likes
    FROM `embeds` e
    LEFT JOIN user_likes ul ON ul.embed_id = e.id AND ul.user_id = 1
    ORDER BY (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM user_likes ula WHERE ula.embed_id = e.id) DESC
)B,
(SELECT @rownum:=0) AS foo
ORDER BY CASE WHEN (@rownum := @rownum + 1) < 6 THEN @rownum ELSE 6 END 
,embed_id
```

Comment: Thank you so much!!!! You are the best, it works. I сould not even imagine such a solution

Comment: You are most welcome @mr.boris. Its always a good feeling when a solution worked :)

Answer (score 0):

You can use `OFFSET 5` with a huge `LIMIT` for your second query. Then reorder the UNION set:

```
(
    SELECT 1 as top5,
           e.id embed_id,
           ...
    FROM `embeds` e ...
    ORDER BY u_likes DESC 
    LIMIT 5
) UNION ALL (
    SELECT 0 as top5,
           e.id embed_id,
           ...
    FROM `embeds` e ...
    ORDER BY u_likes DESC
    LIMIT 99999999999999999999,
    OFFSET 5
)
ORDER BY top5 DESC, embed_id
```

Since there might be ties for `u_likes`, the inner ORDER BY clause will be non deterministic. You should append the primary key columns from both tables, to make the order deterministic. Something like

```
ORDER BY u_likes DESC, e.id, ula.id
```

I'm though not sure if your queries really do what you want, since you will probably get alot of duplicate rows.

Comment: How to exclude second query from the first one in this case?

Comment: @mr.boris It is already excludes due to `OFFSET 5`. The first query returns the first 5 rows. The second query returns all rows **except** of the first 5. `OFFSET 5` means "skip first 5 rows".

Comment: But how do you know what first five ids are? First 5 should be ordered by likes amount and may have random ids thats why we should make first query and then exclude it from the second.

Comment: "First 5 should be ordered by likes" - They are: `ORDER BY u_likes DESC LIMIT 5`. Did you try the query? Isn't it doing what you want?